# OpenVPN clients getting DHCP lease from external server, despite server-bridge used with an DHCP pool

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, dhcp

I have an OpenVPN sever and several clients. My issue is that although I specify a pool for DHCP leases with server-bridge, my clients get a lease from that, but then eventually (after some minutes to some hours) get a lease from the DHCP server on the server side of the LAN. Why?

Server config:

```
port 1494
proto udp
dev tap0
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/keys/ta.key 0
mode server
tls-server
#server-bridge
server-bridge 192.168.1.128 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.80 192.168.1.90
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
mute 20
user nobody
group nobody
auth SHA256
push "route 192.168.1.1"
```

client config:

```
client
dev tap0
proto udp
remote home.chrisseto.com 7825
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
verb 3
mute 20
comp-lzo
```

(inline key section snipped)

Comment: What is the IP address space of the remote DHCP server?

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is the gateway, and it distributes leases from 192.168.1.2 - 50. If you are asking about the subnet mask, it's 255.255.255.0

Comment: Then the problem could be overlapping subnets between the two servers.